# astropy.io.fits: How to append new cards to a header of a fits file?

Tags: python, header, astropy, fits

I'm trying to insert/append new cards to an existing header (the PRIMARY header) of a FITS file. With the code I have below, I can see on the terminal that I am 'successful' in performing this action. But when I open the FITS file in DS9 and check the header info, my new card is not present. So my action is not being saved. What am I missing here?

```
from astropy.io import fits

with fits.open('my.fits') as hdul:
    hdr = hdul[0].header
    hdr.append(('NEWCARD', 'value', 'A comment.'), end=True)
    
    hdul.info()
    print(repr(hdr))
```

Thanks in advance!

Also, would it be better to create a new header and append my new cards there? There's no need to answer this, I'm just curious. Since I'm new to handling fits files, I wonder if that's a better approach.

Answer (score 2):

Indeed with your code you're not saving the updated file. You must use the update mode and call `.flush()`:

```
from astropy.io import fits

with fits.open('my.fits', mode='update') as hdul:
    hdr = hdul[0].header
    hdr.append(('NEWCARD', 'value', 'A comment.'), end=True)
    hdul.flush()  # changes are written back to original.fits
```

https://docs.astropy.org/en/latest/io/fits/#save-file-changes

Comment: The `hdul.flush()` call isn't necessary since that will happen anyways once the file is closed.  It's only necessary if you want to immediately see the updates in the file before closing it.  Perhaps the docs could be clearer about that.